# SKShapeNode filltexture() does not display image

Tags: sprite-kit, skshapenode, sktexture

I want to create a circle that whose content is an image (.png), and based on the SKShapeNode class reference, I thought that I could use SKShapeNode.filltexture() function to set the texture to the image. But when i run the code below, I get the circle, but the image of the "cat-black" I am trying to load doesn't show. I checked that my Image.Assets have the image with the correct name, so something else is up.
Any ideas? I attached the output below:

```
 func newCircle(photo:String, position:CGPoint) -> SKShapeNode {

    let circle = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: 27)
    circle.fillTexture = SKTexture.init(image: UIImage(named: "cat-black")!)
    circle.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    circle.lineWidth = 4
    circle.name = "aggroNode"
    circle.position = position
    return circle

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The documentation states

> The default value is nil. If a fill texture is specified, the fillColor property is ignored and the **filled portion** of the
>   shape node is rendered using the texture instead [emphasis added].

This suggests that the shape must be filled or the texture will not be visible; therefore, if you set the shape's fill color with

```
circle.fillColor = .white
```

the texture will appear. You can also set `fillColor` with a different color to colorize the texture:

```
circle.fillColor = .blue
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue.!

Comment: I've done all this, but can't use one texture from an SKTextureAtlas, instead the entire textureAtlas is being shown inside the circle. Do you know anything about this?