# Xcode Simulator Showing Textures Correctly But Not Device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, texture-atlas, sktextureatlas

I just switched the textures in my SpriteKit game to using a Sprite Atlas. It is all working fine when I test on the Simulator, but on my connected actual iPhone, it does not. All textures in the atlas display in a sort grid pattern, shrunken and warped to fit the SKShapeNode.

Here is the code I'm using

```
let spriteTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites")

override func sceneDidLoad() {

spriteTextureAtlas.preload {}

func spriteCreator() -> SKShapeNode{
        sprite = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: 20)
        sprite.fillTexture = spriteTextureAtlas.textureNamed("spriteTexture")

        return sprite
}
```

I'm sure it is some stupid mistake, but cannot figure out what.

Thanks for the help!

---

### UPDATE

I'm only working with 5 totally seperate textures. If I create a new atlas for every texture, it works fine. This seems inefficient? Or is this what I should be doing, as these textures are not frames of the same animation.

Comment: why do you have sprite and specialOrbNode?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Oh oops! That is a typo in summarizing my code. I'll fix now.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468567/skshapenode-filltexture-does-not-display-image

Comment: @0x141E Unfortunately that did not help me, as their solution was related to textures not showing due to node color. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but my textures weren't showing up on my device or the simulator. I fixed the problem by deleting the folder with my textures in it and creating a new folder using Xcode, and then dragging copies of the images into the folder I created.